# SPListItem question

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I am in the process of learning SharePoint. I am trying to write a simple function to change the selected value of a choice box in a list to approved. I am trying to follow some tutorials online but I can't get the line of code to work. It breaks my function if I include it.

```
SPListItem item;
```

If I remove the code my function executes, but if I include it my function comes back as undefined when I watch it in the debugger. I am not sure why, am I missing a js file reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes since you are using SharePoint JavaScript Object Model. There is no object with type `SPListItem` hence it is returned as `undefined`

`SPListItem` is a Server Side Object.

In client side you are use `SPServices` for updating list items. Or in case of 2010 or 2013 you can use JSOM (JavaScript Object Model)

In case 2013 you can also use REST API.

Comment: I figured it was something was mis matched. Thanks!